E11000 duplicate key error collection: blog-api.blogs index: id_1 dup key: { id: null }
This is my error

E11000 duplicate key error collection: blog-api.blogs index: id_1 dup
key: { id: null }

When i insert one data it is inserting but after that i tried inserting data i am getting above error.
Following is my blogSchema.js


const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const blogSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    author: { type: String, required: true },
    body: { type: String, required: true },
    comments: [{ body: String, date: Date }],
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    picturePath: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    meta: {
      votes: Number,
      favs: Number,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Blog = mongoose.model("Blog", blogSchema);

module.exports = Blog;



This is my add blog function


const addBlog = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { title, author, body } = req.body;
    const picturePath = req.file.filename;
    const result = await Blog.create({
      title: title,
      author: author,
      body: body,
      picturePath: picturePath,
    });
    res.status(200).send(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send("Data format is not valid!");
  }
};



If someone got idea what causing above error please answer it

With your code it is unlikely you can get such an error. Because, for each post request a new _id is created for the new document. And, you dont have any unique fields in your blogSchema definition. Where are you seeing the error and when?

Each MongoDB document has a mandatory _id field (this acts like a Primary Key). If the _id field is not supplied, the MongoDB driver / MongoDB server creates one and creates the document. @DarkBee

The error states id and not _id though? EDIT: These seems to be same fields

At some point you and an id field in your schema marked as unique. You then created a document. This added a unique index in mongodb. You then removed id from your schema but the index still exists. When you now create any document a null is being added as the value to id because you are not providing a value because you think it's not required anymore. Then when you create another document mongodb is telling you it can't have two docs with id:null. Drop the index in Compass or mongosh and then restart your server. Note this error is for id not _id.

The following post has reproduced the issue, discussed some observations, and finally provided a workaround or fix to this case. Please see if it is useful.
Reproducing the issue
Please execute the codes in the given order.
Code 1
The following code defines a schema including the key id, defined it as unique. A new document has also been created in this code. However the key id as such has been omitted from the create method.
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

await main().catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(`Error thrown: ${new Date()}`);
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

async function main() {
  const uri = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test';
  //console.log(`Connecting: ${new Date()}`);
  await mongoose.connect(uri);
  const blogSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
      id: { type: String, unique: true },
      title: { type: String, required: true },
      author: { type: String, required: true },
      body: { type: String, required: true },
      comments: [{ body: String, date: Date }],
      date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
      picturePath: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
      },
      meta: {
        votes: Number,
        favs: Number,
      },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );

  const Blog = mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema);
  const result = await Blog.create({
    title: 'title',
    author: 'author',
    body: 'body',
    picturePath: 'picturePath',
  });
}

Code 2
This is the next code to execute. In this code, the key id has been removed from the schema definition. And while executing this code, it will throw an error as 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.blogs index: id_1 dup key: { id: null }'. However please note that the key id as such has been omitted from the create method in this code as well.
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

await main().catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(`Error thrown: ${new Date()}`);
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

async function main() {
  const uri = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test';
  //console.log(`Connecting: ${new Date()}`);
  await mongoose.connect(uri);
  const blogSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
      title: { type: String, required: true },
      author: { type: String, required: true },
      body: { type: String, required: true },
      comments: [{ body: String, date: Date }],
      date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
      picturePath: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
      },
      meta: {
        votes: Number,
        favs: Number,
      },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );

  const Blog = mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema);
  const result = await Blog.create({
    title: 'title',
    author: 'author',
    body: 'body',
    picturePath: 'picturePath',
  });
}

Observations:
In "Code 1", the key id had been defined and set as unique. While running "Code 1", it automatically created a unique index in the MongoDB database. This can be verified in Mongo Shell as below.
test> db.blogs.getIndexes();
[
  { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_' },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { id: 1 },
    name: 'id_1',
    background: true,
    unique: true
  }
]

In "Code 2" the same key id had been removed from the schema definition.  This time the code had thrown the following error.
'E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.blogs index: id_1 dup key: { id: null }' 

The reason is self explanatory as:

"Code 1" already had created an index entry with a null value.

"Code 2" also tried to create an index entry with another null value and it led to the error.

Please recall in "Code 1" and "Code 2" the key id had been omitted while creating the new documents.


Summary of Observations:

Whenever a key in a Mongoose schema has been defined as unique, then there will be a unique index automatically created for that key in the MongoDB database.

This index creation process does not depend on whether the indexed key has been referenced in the newly created document.

Moreover, if this key has been omitted from the new document, then a null value will automatically be supplied and create an index entry accordingly. The same process will repeat for the same type of document as well which will lead to the error under this context.


The Workaround / fix
The workaround or fix is to manually drop the index as below. Please go to Mongo shell and execute the following command by connecting to the respective database. This will remove the index permanently and will allow new documents to be created without looking for this index anymore.
db.blogs.dropIndex({id:1});


How does this answer the question then? Dropping the index on ID seems like a no-go

Hi @DarkBee, thank you for your care and time in this case. The index is the unwanted object, request please check the latest schema in the original question. At present it did not include it, however it had included in some previous version which is causing the trouble. I am ready to delete my post completely if it is of no use. Please help to me confirm it.

This is actually the correct answer. It reads like some ChatGPT nonsense but you are spot on with id field. Everyone seemed to miss the error was related to id and not _id. OP clearly had an id in their schema then removed it at some point.
